# template literals formatting when sending mail

Tags: javascript, node.js

im sending emails using nodemail and sendgrid. ive structured my email message as the code below but when it is received it looks like that attached image, how can i make the text all align to the left and look normal.

my code

```
var mailOptions = {
                        to: admin.email,
                        from: 'noreply@123.co.uk',
                        subject: 'Admin Account set up',
                        text: `Dear ${admin.name} ${admin.surname},
                    
                    You are receiving this email because your organisation has added you as an admin. To complete the set up, please
                    use the link below to set a new password and sign in.

                    https://${req.headers.host}/reset/${token}

                    Sincerely,

                     HR Team
                 
                 This email was automatically generated by 123

                    `
                    };
```

the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mailOptions = {
    to: admin.email,
    from: 'noreply@123.co.uk',
    subject: 'Admin Account set up',
    text:
`Dear ${admin.name} ${admin.surname},

You are receiving this email because your organisation has added you as an admin. To complete the set up, please
use the link below to set a new password and sign in.

https://${req.headers.host}/reset/${token}

Sincerely,

HR Team

This email was automatically generated by 123`
}
```

Comment: Removing the Tab characters is a good idea. Code readability depends on tabs but in this case it looks like they are added to the string :)